# Unable to invoke pause for Synapse Analytics (workspaces preview)

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I'm able to invoke the api to check the db state, but when I attempt to do a post to the "pause" endpoint, I get the following:

```
The client '7713...' with object id '7713...' has permission to perform action 'Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/pause/action' on scope '/subscriptions/9116.../resourceGroups/workspacemanagedrg-8b.../providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/syeduanalyticscisd3/databases/EduDW/pause'; however, the access is denied because of the deny assignment with name '8ba...' and Id '8ba...' at scope '/subscriptions/9116.../resourceGroups/workspacemanagedrg-8ba...
```

I'm not able to find and/or remove the deny assignment.
Is the pause endpoint not accessible for Synapse Analytics (workspaces preview)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct API to use for Synapse Analytics is this one:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/synapse/sqlpools

I was able to get it working by using this endpoint:
[https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces/{workspaceName}/sqlPools/{sqlPoolName}/pause?api-version=2019-06-01-preview](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%7BsubscriptionId%7D/resourceGroups/%7BresourceGroupName%7D/providers/Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces/%7BworkspaceName%7D/sqlPools/%7BsqlPoolName%7D/pause?api-version=2019-06-01-preview)